# react / typescript documentation in pdf

Tags: reactjs, typescript, documentation

I'm trying to generate a documentation in pdf in my react / typescript project, but I didn't find any lib that generate the documentation in PDF.

I'm using typedoc to generate the documentation right now, but typedoc don't have options to generate in PDF.

I tried to convert HTML generated from typedoc to pdf, but there is some problems with that.
1 - The pdf out put dont looks good.
2 - There is many html files documented to convert.

SO, is there a way to generate a react / typescript documentation in PDF?

Answer (score 0):

If you have html output you can convert it to pdf using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). Provide it print friendly css (I like [Gutenberg](https://github.com/BafS/Gutenberg)).

For example:

```
pandoc -o input.html -t output.pdf --css styles.css
```

Problem with this approach is that css supported by various pandoc engines is quite outdated.

Alternatively provide print friendly css to your html file using [`<link>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), open in browser and press `Ctrl+P` to print it. Print styles will be applied. I usually use this option, since support for modern-ish css is better.

Problem of many html files can easily be solved by pandoc. To merge all html files in current directory use:

`pandoc -s *.html -o output.html`

If document still doesn't look good tweak css stylesheet. Consult [Paged media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media) docs at MDN.